# How to resolve "unused variable" compiler warnings?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

How can I resolve the warnings below?

```
FGlobal FctVoid gtmnts
  PARMLIST((TESPAP, p_var, mantissa, sign),
    hspacbTp  TESPAP  .... 
  )
  #ifdef ASNFAM1
  {
   (void)TESPAP;
   ...
  }
```

> ```
> unused parameter 'TESPAP'
> ```

Comment: Compile with `-DASNFAM1`?

Comment: Which one is it complaining about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is direct way.

1. use --Wunused-value with gcc this will suppress all warnings for unused value in source code.
2. As Sourav mentioned in comment try adding -DASNFAM1 while compiling if you want to conditionally compile it.
3. add `#ifdef ASNFAM1` at all occurrences.

I will recommend third option as it is fail proof.
but sometimes we need quick hack so give other 2 a try.
Quick suggestion:- try not to ignore/suppress compiler warnings as they are there for a reason.

Comment: Huh? The `void`-cast is the idiomatic way to "use" an otherwise unused parameter, so it's already there. From the code in the question, it's unclear why this is inside an `#ifdef`, and I really don't see how more `#ifdef`s would help here.

Comment: good point Felix. reason for that is he is using it as argument in function parameter. so there is possibility he has two ways he wants his function to be defined. here the function body is in ifdef so I thought it will be better if the declaration also in ifdef.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean, but it's often not a good idea to change the interface depending on compilation flags.

Comment: Totally agreed. but if you consider programing as a art. every one has there unique style. so people tend to not do things that are right than which way they see will work. here we tell them the right way but not that is the only way. mostly novice programmer gets pleasure just getting something work. eventually he will understand the rules of the game. So I think let people be aware of right way but let them explore there paths freely.

Comment: I added(void)TESPAP; to resolve the warning but still showing.

Comment: it is because , that part of code (void TESPAP) is not compiled because of `ifdef`  if you want to check try -E switch of gcc to get preprocessor output.